# Understanding the results of boost::random statistic-tests

Tags: c++, boost, random

I need to check the quality of boost::random generators. I ran the tests from statistic_tests.hpp on 3 of them:

```
Confidence level: 0.99; 1-alpha = 0.01; chi_square(19, 36.1909) = 0.99
Running tests on rand48                                               
KS: 24.08 22.64                                                       
equidistribution: 18.16 14.88   2D: 19.6 12.8                         
runs: up: 15.12 42.48* [0.00152604]   down: 23.92 27.84               
gaps: 16.08 15.2                                                      
poker: 33.52 55.44* [1.98986e-05]                                     
coupon collector: 17.68 14.72                                         
permutation: 17.52 17.12                                              
maximum-of-t: 23.28 13.52                                             
birthday spacing: 24.1333 14.9333                                     

Running tests on mt11213b
KS: 25.36 20.8           
equidistribution: 9.84 18.64   2D: 12.72 20.48 
runs: up: 37.84* [0.0062191] 6.32   down: 12.4 7.2 
gaps: 15.6 14.88
poker: 26.96 15.28
coupon collector: 15.6 13.28
permutation: 18.32 25.44
maximum-of-t: 26.32 38.56* [0.00503301]
birthday spacing: 20.9333 21.8667

Running tests on mt19937
KS: 21.36 19.2
equidistribution: 22.16 20.88   2D: 29.2 18
runs: up: 16.72 19.04   down: 21.68 37.6* [0.00666986]
gaps: 12.72 19.2
poker: 18.48 14.8
coupon collector: 18 11.76
permutation: 17.04 22.8
maximum-of-t: 14.96 22.08
birthday spacing: 19.6 10.6667
```

The problem is, I don't know how to read the results...
Somebody can help?

Comment: [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) is probably more appropriate for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty broad if you do not understand statistical testing...but anyway, the output relates to critical values of various test-statistics (formed from various statistical tests) related to well-known statistical/probabilistic problems: Poker, Coupon collector, equidistribution, etc.

All the information is contained [here](https://www.rw.ethz.ch/alumni/thesis/Ruetti_Mario_Diplomarbeit.pdf), and the links contained there.

If you need to brush up on statisitical inference and statisitcal tests, then as *MooseBoys* says, [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) will be a happier place for you.